# C - Pipe input from one program to another program

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm supposed to create two programs (main and aux), where main forks a child to execute aux. The parent takes input from the user, until blank line '\n', and the child executes aux, which is supposed to print the input back out. I'm able to get it to work in main with the commented code instead of execlp(), but cannot get execlp(aux) to work correctly. Any help is appreciated.

"main.c"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fd[2], i;
    char line[100], buffer[100];

    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
            printf("Fork Failed\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
            close(fd[0]);
            while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) && line[0] != '\n') {
                    write(fd[1], line, sizeof(line));
            }
            close(fd[1]);
    }
    else {
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

            //while(read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
            //      printf("> %s", buffer);

            execlp("./aux", "aux", (char *)0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"aux.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char data[100];

    while(fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin))
            printf(">%s\n", data);

    return 0;
}
```

sample input/output

```
this
>this

is a test
>
> test

only prints larger text with random \n
>
>ts larger text with random \n
```

Comment: hi, you are executing a new image with exec*() family, which completely replaces original image. Like program text, heap, stack etc.

Comment: Read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and man pages like [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger `gdb`** and [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). Add debugging `printf`. Check that `execlp` did not fail (e.g. by following it with `perror("execlp");` ....)

Comment: You should close `fd[0]` in the child after duplicating it to standard input.  This time, you get away with it; you won't always do so.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was able to get it working by replacing sizeof(line), with strlen(line). I also added the perror, and close(fd[0]) where you guys mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is wrong (you always `write` 100 bytes even for shorter `line`-s):

```
                write(fd[1], line, sizeof(line)); // WRONG
```

should probably be using [strlen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html)

```
            size_t ll = strlen(line);
            ssize_t wc = write(fd[1], line, ll);
            if (wc != ll)
              fprintf(stderr, "write was wrong (only %d, wanted %d) - %s\n",
                      (int) wc, (int) ll, strerror(errno));
```

Since you want to write only the filled bytes of the `line` buffer, not always 100 bytes each time (some of them not being initialized).

In your case `sizeof(data)` is 100 since you declared `char data[100];`

Please read carefully the documentation of every used function (and also [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or some other book on Unix/POSIX/Linux programming). The documentation of [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) and of [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) tells that you need to add:

```
  #include <string.h>
  #include <errno.h>
```

Actually, if you want to use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) directly (without [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)) you should prefer using larger buffers (e.g. 4Kbytes each at least for efficiency) and you need to manage partial `read`-s and `write`-s and do your buffering by yourself.

BTW, compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). In general, be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (however, at a first glance, your program don't seem to have UB).

Notice that [execlp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html) could fail. Consider adding some call to [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) after it.

Comment: Thank you! strlen fixed it right up. I also put in the code that you, Basile Starynkevitch, and Jonathan Leffler mentioned to error check. This is the first C class I take, and the professor never went over gdb debugger. I'll be sure to look into it. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: You surely need to learn how to use `gdb`. Its documentation has a nice tutorial page.